# Simplify $\gcd{(b-a,c-a)}$

Tags: number-theory

Is there any way to simplify $$\gcd{(b-a,c-a)}$$ where all $a,b,c$ are integers?

Is there any other way  to write/simplify this?

Comment: @pjs36 I don't know what you mean, but I know that if $x=\gcd(b-a,c-a)$, then there exists $s,t$ such that $x=(b-a)s+(c-a)t$. But how does this help?

Comment: My guess is that just about the only thing you can say is that $b\equiv c\pmod{\gcd(b-a,c-a)}$.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify? If you mean to reduce it to two variables, I don't think that's possible. You haven't given any additional information. Is it like $a, b, c$ are relatively prime in pairs?

Comment: @Dhruv As I said a,b,c can be any integers

Comment: What do you mean by simplify?

Comment: That seems pretty darned simple to me.

Comment: A common factor could either be common factor to all 3 a,b,c, or it could be common to none but a-c and b-c and determinable by neither.  I don't see there being any way to be more specific.

Comment: I mean the gcd(12-5,19-5)=7.  I can't see any way of re-expressing this in terms of 5,12,19.  That's not to say it can't be but I can't see it made simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The g.c.d. of two numbers must divide both their sum and difference. Hence in your example, if $g=\gcd(b-a,c-a)$, then
$$g \mid \bigl((b-a)+(c-a)\bigr) = (b+c-2a)$$
and
$$g \mid \bigl((b-a)-(c-a)\bigr) = (b-c).$$
So
$$\gcd(b-a,c-a)=\gcd(b-c,b+c-2a).$$
But I wouldn't exactly call that "simplified", except that the $a$ is contained to a single element.

Comment: Nice answer.  I wouldn't call that simplified either though.  In fact I'd definitely call it less simple.